# is it possible to "decrypt" an F77_UNFORMATTED (IEEE-unformatted) datafile?

Tags: c++, linux, fortran, idl, fortran77

I porting some code wrote in **IDL** to **C++**, but the datafile is in **F77_UNFORMATTED** **IEEE-unformatted**. I can't open directly the data (it's a very big file), so I tried naively to do something like :

```
  std::ifstream results(dataFile);
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 200 ; i++ )
  {
    std::cout <<" {{"<< results.rdbuf() << "}} " << std::endl;

  }
```

I got some s... print,

```
B??$B?}B?5?A\?@0\???A?R???=??fdA=-???y?9@AB?N3B,TB???@t?A??!B??BS,??BX??B?l?B[B?]?A?AqB?B?B?C?B1?A2?
```

I checked by copying with `awk` the first 200 lines, and I got the same stuff.

I would like to avoid solution like reading and saving everything from **IDL** in a friendly format.

**`xxd datafile | more` returns:**

```
0000000: 0080 1700 6d20 10b9 17f0 1c39 d245 24b9  ....m .....9.E$.
0000010: 2535 1b39 251b 39b9 07f7 1939 bba4 4db9  %5.9%.9....9..M.
0000020: f428 1939 dfb7 63b9 7ba2 1a39 f293 7ab9  .(.9..c.{..9..z.
0000030: dc1d 1e39 1b49 89b9 bb53 2139 b3f1 94b9  ...9.I...S!9....
0000040: 7071 2639 a8e2 a0b9 1a02 2a39 79b3 acb9  pq&9......*9y...
0000050: 5092 2f39 b570 b8b9 637f 3539 66d4 c4b9  P./9.p..c.59f...
0000060: 197c 3e39 06f5 cfb9 d6cf 4639 c825 dbb9  .|>9......F9.%..
0000070: 3762 5039 42df e5b9 06e7 5739 3575 efb9  7bP9B.....W95u..
0000080: c885 6039 e6e6 f8b9 fedb 6839 54b4 00ba  ..`9......h9T...
0000090: 2480 7239 bbea 04ba b1b3 7b39 902f 08ba  $.r9......{9./..
00000a0: a388 8239 084c 0bba be67 8639 324c 0dba  ...9.L...g.92L..
00000b0: b020 8b39 844b 0fba 4297 8e39 f38d 10ba  . .9.K..B..9....
00000c0: b6ee 9239 a055 11ba 2e73 9639 640f 11ba  ...9.U...s.9d...
00000d0: ed11 9939 1f33 10ba 97df 9a39 8152 0eba  ...9.3.....9.R..
00000e0: 65de 9c39 863e 0cba b5b0 9e39 3fe2 08ba  e..9.>.....9?...
00000f0: ae9b a039 ac81 05ba 098f a139 81d9 00ba  ...9.......9....
0000100: ae04 a239 b295 f7b9 8f56 a139 315f ecb9  ...9.....V.91_..
0000110: 2c5d a139 b19f e0b9 6f2d a139 5e0e d4b9  ,].9....o-.9^...
0000120: 96e0 a039 f24e c7b9 7b36 a039 cc1d b9b9  ...9.N..{6.9....
0000130: 338d 9e39 33ff aab9 5a4e 9c39 6aa9 9cb9  3..93...ZN.9j...
0000140: 0c3a 9a39 a6b0 8eb9 7760 9839 2bd3 80b9  .:.9....w`.9+...
0000150: 94ae 9539 6ea4 67b9 6c0e 9339 60d0 4cb9  ...9n.g.l..9`.L.
0000160: cda8 8f39 3274 33b9 e11c 8c39 ac0a 1bb9  ...92t3....9....
```

**maybe some useful information:**

the **IDL** program reads the datafile trough a `for` loop,

```
  for i=0, imax do begin
    ReadU, d_file, a 
    ReadU, d_file, b
    ReadU, d_file, c
    ReadU, d_file, d
    ReadU, d_file, e
    ReadU, d_file, f
    ReadU, d_file, g
    ReadU, d_file, h

    .... DO MATHS AND STUFFS ....
  endfor
```

all variables `a` to `h` are `fltarr(sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ)` (3D matrix with `sixeX` = 128, `sizeY` = 64 and `sizeZ` = 47). So I guess `readU` reads in the file, at each call, a matrice and assigns it to the associated variable.

Comment: Do you know the f77 format(s) used to write the file? If so, it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: It might be easier to decrypt if you read the data as 32-bit integers, 32-bit floats or 64-bit doubles, assuming that it was produced on the same architecture and that the endianess is the same.

Comment: Try using `xxd datafile | more` and pasting the first few lines into your question - and add any info you may have about the first few values.

Comment: @mpez0 no, but I can ask someone who should be able to answer that.

Comment: @cup I can only guess (for now) it was computed on the same architecture. I will think about the rest of your comment

Comment: @MarkSetchell done, I can also try to grab some data directly from IDL. (right now I have to leave...)

Comment: What is the type of `fltarr`, and what are the values of `sizeX`, `sizeY` and `sizeZ` and what is the size of the datafile in bytes?

Comment: @MarkSetchell fltarr means float array, sizeX =128, sizeY=64, sizeZ=47. datafile has 206608031808 bytes (2TB if I read correctly) (get by wc -c datafile). Architecture of the server is 64bit

Comment: If there are 8 arrays (a-h), each with 128x64x47 elements that means each array element takes up 206608031808/(8x128x64x47) bytes, or 67,076 bytes per element which means they are not 4 byte floats, or there is something else in the file....

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I can't say... I'll talk with my tutor ASAP.

Comment: @MarkSetchell does this help : the format is IEEE-unformatted

Comment: @mpez0  the format is IEEE-unformatted

Comment: what do you know about `imax`? As Mark Setchell there must be more data then just eight arrays of the size 128x64x47 in the file. The first integer tells, that the size of one array (if we assume that every call of a write-function is for one array) is 1540096 byte. Since you have 385024 elements in one array you have 4 bytes per element which could be a single precision (float). But eight times such a array leads to a files size of about 12 mb!

Comment: your first problem right out of the box is your `c++` doesn't even attempt to interpret the byte stream as any particular numeric type. You need to learn the basics of reading binary data in `c++` before even worrying about this particular file ( there are thousands of examples readily found by google )

Comment: @agentp . I didn't know that is a binary file. Since monday I havent worked on this because I'm very busy. I was thinking to read tomorrow the data as you think.